# Require more than one reviewer when reviewing documentation changes

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, documentation, revision-history, draft

Example, [this draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/drafts/26161).

The edit introduced plainly incorrect information. The edit was rejected by one user, with a clear reason:

> Contains factually incorrect information.
>   I might be mistaken, but after some reading, I don't believe % is a unary operator. I also think that ++ and -- are assignments.

(This reason *is* correct)

Yet somehow, someone else could simply approve the edit, meaning we'd have to revert the changes, and the earlier rejection is simply ignored.

Comment: I've asked @AdamLear multiple times for increasing it, but just got a reply they'd be still monitoring… mh… But yep, such examples are exactly the problem.

Comment: I think then reviewing would become a bottleneck. I also have seen rejections because of very minor problems or stupid reasons. I would rather trust in the community, that big issues will be corrected soon by others. or it would be useful a quick editing functionality at reviewing, so reviewers could fix typos and minor things.

Comment: @deeenes: At this moment, a review requires only 1 accept vote, or 2 rejections. That just makes it too easy to approve junk edits.